# How can I add support for Brave browser in profile-sync-daemon

Tags: daemon, browser, tmpfs

[Profile-sync-daemon](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Profile-sync-daemon) can be installed in Debian based systems with `sudo apt install profile-sync-daemon` and in Arch based systems with `sudo pacman -S profile-sync-daemon`, but it lacks native support for Brave browser. How can I add support for Brave?

Answer (score 1):

An extra configuration step from this [Github page: Add Brave Browser/Files Changed](https://github.com/graysky2/profile-sync-daemon/pull/262/files) is needed. Therefore I decided to write this answer for my own use and possibly to help others.

In Arch based systems one can also install a specific daemon `profile-sync-daemon-brave` from AUR, in which case this extra step is not needed.

1. Create a new file `brave` in `/usr/share/psd/browsers` that contains:

   ```bash
   DIRArr[0]="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser"
   PSNAME="brave"
   ```
2. Possibly in `~/.config/psd/psd.conf`  you must keep the default - all browsers - as commented.
3. Preview status of `profile-sync-daemon`:

   `psd parse`
4. Possibly you need to `restart daemon`:

   ```bash
   # for current user
   systemctl --user restart psd.service
   ```

   ```bash
   # for all users
   logout / reboot
   ```

   or if that does not help

   ```bash
   # for all users
   sudo systemctl --global disable psd.service
   logout / reboot
   sudo systemctl --global enable psd.service
   logout / reboot
   ```